# Testing if method with Promise was called (Jest)

Tags: promise, jestjs, sinon

I have an initializer method calling another method that returns a promise, like:

```
  initStuffAfterLoad() {
    const _this = this;
    const theInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
      if (thing) {
        window.clearInterval(theInterval);
        _this.getBanana()
          .then(response => {
            _this.getApple(response, _this);
          });
      }
    }, 100);
  }
```

and am needing to test whether `getBanana` was called (jest/sinon). So far I have:

```
  test('init function calls getBanana', () => {
    let thing = true
    const getBananaSpy = sinon.spy();
    sinon.stub(TheClass.prototype, 'getBanana').callsFake(getBananaSpy).resolves();

    jest.useFakeTimers();
    TheClass.prototype.initStuffAfterLoad();
    jest.runOnlylPendingTimers();

    expect(getBananaSpy.called).toBeTruthy();
    TheClass.prototype.getBanana.restore();
 });
```

However it still receives `false` at the assertion. I figure I'm not handling the Promise part correctly - what is the best practice way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with sinon, but here is a way to achieve your need with pure jest (even better it also checks that getApple is called when getBanana reseolves :))

```
jest.useFakeTimers()

const _this = {
    getBanana: () => {},
    getApple: () => {}
}

const initStuffAfterLoad = () => {
    const theInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
        window.clearInterval(theInterval);
        _this.getBanana().then(response => {
            _this.getApple(response, _this)
        });
    }, 100);
}

test('', () => {
    let result

    _this.getBanana = jest.fn(() => {
        result = new Promise( resolve => { resolve() } )
        return result
    })
    _this.getApple = jest.fn()

    initStuffAfterLoad()    

    jest.runAllTimers()
            
    expect(_this.getBanana.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
    return result.then(() => {
        expect(_this.getApple.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
    })
})
```

code tested :)

---

> PASS  test\temp.test.js   √  (25ms)
>
> Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
>
> Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
>
> Snapshots:   0 total
>
> Time:        2.489s

Comment: Thanks very much! good to know with the pure jest implementation